# Issue With Radio Button

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I am writing a program in Java using Htmlunit that has a Radio Button that needs to be clicked to fill out a set of information. I am currently having an issue finding the fields that need to be entered after the radio button is clicked. Currently my code is:

```
String url = "http://cpdocket.cp.cuyahogacounty.us/";

final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
final HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);
final HtmlElement button = form.getElementById("SheetContentPlaceHolder_btnYes");
final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
try {
  synchronized (page2) {
    page2.wait(3000);
  }
}
catch(InterruptedException e)
{
  System.out.println("error");
}

//returns the first page after the security page
final HtmlForm form2 = page2.getForms().get(0);
final HtmlRadioButtonInput button2 = form2.getInputByValue("forcl");
button2.setDefaultChecked(true);
page2.refresh();
final HtmlForm form3 = page2.getForms().get(0);
form3.getInputByName("ctl00$SheetContentPlaceHolder$foreclosureSearch$txtZip").setValueAttribute("44106");
final HtmlSubmitInput button3 = form3.getInputByValue("Submit");
final HtmlPage page3 = button3.click();
try {
  synchronized (page3) {
    page2.wait(10000);
  }
}
catch(InterruptedException e)
{
  System.out.println("error");
}
```

While the first page is a security page that needs to be bypassed, the second page is where I am running into the issue as I am getting the error "

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[input] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[ctl00$SheetContentPlaceHolder$foreclosureSearch$txtZip]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm.getInputByName(HtmlForm.java:463)
    at Courtscraper.scrapeWebsite(Courtscraper.java:58)"
```

I believe this means that the input field cannot be found in the form. I have been referring to two websites as reference. [Website1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747097/htmlunit-click-on-radio-button-input-not-working-as-expected), [Website2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556200/htmlunit-button-click). I am not sure, but i believe I may have to create a new HtmlPage after setting the radio button to true.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the page it is impossible to see why the error is happening. However, as you say, it is clear that the `getInputByName` is not finding the element and raising the exception.

Given that code, and assuming you've not committed a syntactical error in the string to fetch the input by name, I would suggest removing this line:

```
page2.refresh();
```

Refreshing the page after making modifications to it might result in getting an unmodified page again.

Regarding creating a new HtmlPage after setting the radio button to true, that would only be necessary if the radio has an `onchange` or a similar event attached that fires a JavaScript AJAX call that modifies the DOM and creates the element that you are trying to fetch.

That's all I can suggest given that code.

Comment: By not refreshing the page, the form stays the same as before the radiobutton was pressed. Through this form, I am not able to find the correct fields to type into. How would I go about retrieving the new form to obtain the new fields after the radiobutton have been pressed?

Comment: I took a quick look at the page and I see what is going on. That page performs an AJAX request once a radio button is clicked. You will need to perform a wait after it is clicked so that the page gets updated. You can take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843521) to see what I'm talking about

Comment: That makes sense, after the AJAX request is performed, should the form update allowing for the proper fields to be referenced?

Comment: It should, unless the JavaScript code throws one of those infamous HTMLUnit's `ScriptException`s :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code after creating page2 you will make a `WebRequest` not creating a new page like this.

```
String url = "http://cpdocket.cp.cuyahogacounty.us/Search.aspx";
String EventTarget = "ctl00$SheetContentPlaceHolder$rbCivilForeclosure";
String world = "ctl00$SheetContentPlaceHolder$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$SheetContentPlaceHolder$rbCivilForeclosure";
String Viewstate = page2.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").getAttribute("value");
String EventValidation = page2.getElementById("__EVENTVALIDATION").getAttribute("value");

WebRequest req1 = new WebRequest(new URL(url));
req1.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
req1.setAdditionalHeader("Origin", "http://cpdocket.cp.cuyahogacounty.us");
req1.setAdditionalHeader("Referer", "http://cpdocket.cp.cuyahogacounty.us/Search.aspx");
req1.setAdditionalHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

String txtview1 = "ctl00$ScriptManager1=" + URLEncoder.encode(world) + "&__EVENTTARGET=" + URLEncoder.encode(EventTarget) + "&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=" + URLEncoder.encode(Viewstate) + "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + URLEncoder.encode(EventValidation) + "&ctl00$SheetContentPlaceHolder$rbSearches=forcl&__ASYNCPOST=true&";
//System.out.println("this is text view =============== " + txtview1);
req1.setRequestBody(txtview1);
req1.setAdditionalHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
String re=client.getPage(req1).getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
System.out.println("========== " + re);
```

After done above code successfully you getting a String in which your response is come.